# Cassandra experiencing OutOfMemory issues (Java Heap Space) on long runs

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

We are experimenting a bit with Cassandra by trying out some of the long running test cases (stress test) and we are experiencing some memory issues on one node of the cluster at any given time (It could be any machine on the cluster!)

We am running DataStax Community with Cassandra 1.1.6 on a machine with Windows Server 2008 and 8 GB of RAM. Also, we have configured the Heap size to be 2GB as against the default value of 1GB.

A snippet from the logs:

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Dumping heap to java_pid2440.hprof ...

Heap dump file created [1117876234 bytes in 11.713 secs]

ERROR 22:16:56,756 Exception in thread Thread[CompactionExecutor:399,1,main]

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FastByteArrayOutputStream.expand(FastByteArrayOutputStream.java:104)

at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FastByteArrayOutputStream.write(FastByteArrayOutputStream.java:220)

at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)

Any pointers/help to investigate and fix this.??

Comment: could you give more details of what you are inserting and where you are insterting it (key, column names, etc...)? what settings have you used for declaring your cluster and keyspaces? any details might be relevant.

Comment: I am creating the keyspace with the following command:CREATE KEYSPACE T_V_0 with placement_strategy = 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy' and strategy_options = {replication_factor:1};

Comment: The columns basically have a DateType, UUIDType, 3 IntegerType, 2 LongType and 1 DoubleType with  WITH comparator = UTF8Type
 AND key_validation_class = UTF8Type
 AND default_validation_class = UTF8Type

Comment: Are you inserting always at the same address (key + column name)? Don't you get write errors on some writes since UTF8Type is not compatible with other validation (you should probably leave as bytes ... which is a default that allows you to have multiple types of columns in one row).

Comment: Nope, I do not insert at the same address. The column names are UTF8Type and the unique key that I am using is a combination of UUID and TimeStamp, so there is never a overlap. I am able to insert data sucessfully. Only when I insert over 1 Billion records continuously, one of the nodes in the cluster fails with OutOfMemory exception. This could be any node but I believe its mostly the node that accepts maximum connection from the client.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing the right thing by long-running your load tests but in a production use case you wouldn't be writing data like this.

Your rows are probably growing too big to fit in RAM when it comes time to compact them. A compaction requires the entire row to fit in RAM.

There's also a hard limit of 2 billion columns per row but in reality you shouldn't ever let rows grow that wide. Bucket them by adding a day or server name or some other value common across your dataset to your row keys.

For a "write-often read-almost-never" workload you can have very wide rows but you shouldn't come close to the 2 billion column mark. Keep it in millions with bucketing.

For a write/read mixed workload where you're reading entire rows frequently even hundreds of columns may be too much.

If you treat Cassandra right you'll easily handle thousands of reads and writes per second per node. I'm seeing about 2.5k reads and writes concurrently per node on my main cluster.

Comment: I increased the JAVA Heap size to about 4GB and there is an improvement in the write throughput. Also as you mentioned rightly, I have very wide rows (timestamped data for every day). I might think of changing the granularity to may be every hour rather than 24 hours. The rows might get really big otherwise.

Comment: Do you think reverse comparator might help in this case?

Comment: Don't increase heap size unless you're sure you understand why you're doing it. Increasing heap size will firstly increase pause times for garbage collections which often makes things worse, secondly takes memory away from the kernel file cache, which at least for me on Linux proved far quicker than Cassandra caches and lastly for your scenario will only delay the OOM, not prevent it.Changing anything in the cassandra-env file is a bad idea unless you fully understand why you're doing it.

Comment: Also, bucketing as you did is the right way to handle this kind of data but a reverse comparator won't make a difference to your OOM issue but might better for your access pattern? Only you could tell me that tho.

Comment: I was reading through Oracle documentation on GC @ http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html and I stumbled upon this on the use of ParallelGC, which I am sure DataStax Cassandra is configured for:

Comment: Excessive GC Time and OutOfMemoryError
The parallel collector will throw an OutOfMemoryError if too much time is being spent in garbage collection: if more than 98% of the total time is spent in garbage collection and less than 2% of the heap is recovered, an OutOfMemoryError will be thrown. This feature is designed to prevent applications from running for an extended period of time while making little or no progress because the heap is too small. If necessary, this feature can be disabled by adding the option -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit to the command line.

Comment: If anyone has used the DataStax Cassandra on Windows and have configured the -Xmx, -Xms, -NewSize and -MaxNewSize, please share your rationale behind them.